# Template variables conditions

Tags: templates, conditionals, configuration-variables

Im on Expression engine 7 now.
Im trying check template variable for condition. like so:

```
{if site_logo_path != ""}
    <img src="{site_logo_path}">
{if:else}
    <h1>Site Name</h1>
{/if}
```

Im tryed:

```
{if {site_logo_path} != ""}
{if "{site_logo_path}" != ""}
{if '{site_logo_path}' != ""}
```

No one is working correctly. If site_logo_path is empty string or url
always displays second rule with h1.

Thanks for your attention. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Does your {site_logo_path} is a normal variable or it come from a layout:set?

Did you try {if !site_logo_path} ?

Comment: Thanks for ypur reply. Its normal template variable and i use it in layout. And yes, im tried that.

Comment: Does {site_logo_path} output something by itself?!

Answer (score 0):

Where is `{site_logo_path}` coming from?

**Is it a layout variable?**

`{layout:set name="site_logo_path"}/some/path/file.png{/layout:set}`

If so you would use in your if statement:

`{layout:site_logo_path}`

**Is it a channel field?**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="some_channel"}
    {site_logo_path}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If so, it needs to be wrapped in a channel entries loop like above.

**Is it a global template variable?**

Then what you have tried should've worked.

**Is it a template partial?**

Then I don't think you can evaluate it in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If it's like you want to show path then you can try this

```
{if site_logo_path && site_logo_path != ""}
Your condition to show logo
{if:else}
show else 
{/if}
```

This should do the trick. If this does not work, let me know what is your purpose and I will help you.